# why sampling weights that I have range from 1, not 0?

Tags: weighted-sampling

I am looking at a dataset from Pew Research Center. Inside the dataset, different survey waves have their own weight variable with sampling weights. I thought in general it is supposed to range from 0 with positive values, denoting the possibility to be drawn. **However, some survey weights seem to range from 1 instead of 0, and the values are also very extreme (for example up to 50~60).**

It does not quite look like what I understand as sampling weights... But there are not further explanations in more detail attached to the dataset. Am I getting something wrong here? Anybody please help.

Comment: *"denoting the possibility to be drawn"* Not necessarily, most sample weights are IPW: Inversed probability weight, which is 1/(probability to be drawn). It briefly denotes how many other people this case is representing. Yet, survey methodology is vast, it's best to consult the Pew data analyst guidebook.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, Pew data analyst guidebook does not provide detailed explanation of the weighted variables in the data. I tried to sum up the values, but it did not seem to be either the number of population or sample size, which is weird.

Comment: Perhaps start from [here](https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/u-s-survey-research/our-survey-methodology-in-detail/)?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected for sampling weights, as @Penguin_knight says in their comment.  They are sampling weights, not probabilities.

In addition, sampling weights can be rescaled without it affecting your results. If you want, you can divide all the weights by 2 (meaning that they would range from 0.5).

Weights can be more intuitive than sampling probabilities. Imagine I know that my sample is comprised of equal numbers of males and females. My sample has 1 male, and 50 females. That male needs to have a weight of 50 to make the sample representative of the population.

(Alternatively, and equivalently, the females could have a probability of 1 and the male 0.02).

Comment: thanks for the comment. It looks like I should be able to get the number of entire population when I sum up the sampling weights; unfortunately, that's not the case to me. What should I do?

Comment: Oh, now that I think about your comment again, I think I get what you mean. As long as it represents the sampling weights, I am supposed to be able to transform the values to make them add up to the sample size, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Sometimes weights are scaled so that they do add to the population size, but not always.